# Restyling hover on Material UI IconButton - the matter of "ellipse" or "shadow"

Tags: uibutton, material-ui

I know there were few similar questions, but my request is slightly different.
I have already definded focus color of "ellipse" or "shadow" and icon itself that appears around IconButton (containing HighLightOffIcon):

```
const iconColor ='#F70000';
const MyDelete = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: iconColor,
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
})(HighlightOffIcon);
```

And that is OK - the shadow takes "diluted" appearance and desired color.
Wanted, however, have the same picture on hover, and believed the code will do the job is:

```
const iconColor ='#F70000';
const MyDelete = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: iconColor,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    '&:hover': {
      background: "iconColor",
   },
   
  },
})(HighlightOffIcon);
```

But it doesn't work - the on-hover-shadow is still dark and not reddish. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: did you try `background: iconColor`?

Comment: Thanks, you are definitely right that it is typo, but corrected doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Finally:

```
const iconColor ='#7ac221';
const iconHoverColor ='rgba(122,194,33,0.34)'
const MyIconButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: iconColor,
    "&:hover":{backgroundColor: iconHoverColor,}
  },
  
})(IconButton);


const MyMoreInfo = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: iconColor,
    cursor: 'pointer',
   
  },
})(InfoIcon);
```